# What is the recommended method for creating a library with multiple classes?

Tags: c++, qt

I am relatively new to C++ (previous experience in Python and dabbled in Java) and I am writing a small program as a familiarization project. As part of the program I am writing a class to decode some data and will eventually write a similar one that will perform the encoding. The code is something that I am sure I will reuse quite often and thought it would be interesting to create a library as part of the project.
My question is, what is considered the best practice for creating a library?

**Edit: (Revised)**

After asking this question, I realized that I didn't know what I didn't know. I have done some more research and this should help make my question more specific:

- I am developing in Qt Creator. So specifics relating to Qt would be helpful, but not necessary.
- I have created a new static library project in Qt (MyCodec) that, currently, has one class defined called MyDecoder.
- As a library, my assumption is that, to add MyEncoder, I just create another class/header file.
- What happens next is where I am uncertain. Do I just build the library? My understanding is that it will create (in Windows) a .lib and a .h file. Is there something I should do before this step? Are there options that will affect the way I interact with it?
- Do I just include that header file in my program to access both classes that I wrote?
- I found lots of answers on adding a .lib file to a project in Qt, so I don't need that information.

**Original Question: (for context)**

My initial thought is that it would be the most convenient to create MyLib that includes both MyEncoder and MyDecoder classes.

- If I were to do it that way, do I just declare both classes in the header?
- I would like to create a DLL out of this library for portability and experience. I'm sure there is lots of information out there about creating and using DLLs (which is not the subject of this question), but if there is a particularly good tutorial (for Qt) please pass it along.
- My assumption is that it would be best to use separate namespaces for MyEncoder and MyDecoder for this implementation vs. one namespace for MyLib?

I can see one trade off of this method being the size of the application, since including MyLib.h would include the code for the encoder and decoder (if the encoder and decoder were separate applications). This is assuming I am not using a DLL.

I guess what I am getting at is:

- What methods are available (and recommended)?
- What are the trade offs of each?
- Where can I find documentation (tutorials/examples) on this specific subject? My search efforts have not yielded much for results.

If it helps to be more specific, I am doing my development using Qt 4.7.4 in Qt Creator.

Comment: How about `namespace My { class Decoder; class Encoder; }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One "best practice" in C++ with regards to libraries is typically "you pay for what you use."

How this applies to your question is that you would have MyEncoder and MyDecoder in separate header files. So if the user wants to use a MyEncoder he would include MyEncoder.h, if he wanted to use MyDecoder he would include MyDecoder.h, and if he wanted to use both he would include both headers.

The linker will typically only include the parts of the code that you use in the executable, so there is no penalty as far as code size goes, but there is a penalty in compile times, particularly if you start using advanced template techniques in your classes. Compile times can get pretty long in large projects, so it is important to be able to only include what you are going to use.

Of course, sometimes it is also convenient to include everything with one header. So what you could have is this:

- MyEncoder.h
- MyDecoder.h
- MyCodec.h

and then MyCodec.h could include both MyEncoder.h and MyDecoder.h

There is probably no good reason to have MyEncoder and MyDecoder in different namespaces, assuming they are meant to operate on the same type of data.

You might want to have something like a MyCodec namespace, and declare MyEncoder and MyDecoder within that namespace.

**Updated for your revision:**

> As a library, my assumption is that, to add MyEncoder, I just create
>   another class/header file.

That is a correct assumption.

> What happens next is where I am uncertain. Do I just build the
>   library? My understanding is that it will create (in Windows) a .lib
>   and a .h file. Is there something I should do before this step? Are
>   there options that will affect the way I interact with it?

I haven't used Qt creator in a while, so I can't speak with authority on it or how to access the relevant options. But as a general rule you will want to have at least 2 versions of your library; a debug version and a release version. If your library uses the Qt libraries, then when an application links to the debug version of your library, they will need to have the debug version of the Qt shared libraries in their path, and if they link to your release version they will need to have the release version of the Qt libs.

There may also be options of whether you want to statically link to the C++ standard runtime libraries, or dynamically link to the DLLs.

But essentially yes, you just build the library and then the application that uses it will link the library to the executable.

> Do I just include that header file in my program to access both
>   classes that I wrote?

You include the header file, and link to the .lib file. That's all you should need to do.

Comment: This directly answers one of my questions and validates my thinking. In the process of writing this question and reading/researching the responses, I realized I didn't know what I didn't know. I have since realized that I can create a "C++ Library" project in Qt, which I assume compiles to a .lib file in Windows? I haven't found what I feel is a good reference / tutorial on creating a C++ library in Qt though. I will revise my original question to clarify.

Comment: The reason that I thought it would be good to have separate namespaces is that I may want to have methods like setEncoding() or setEncodingLibrary() in each class to create a consistent user experience and separate namespaces would allow that.

Comment: It occurred to me that the methods will be in separate classes and therefore already have their own namespaces and that I do want to put both classes in a MyCodec namespace. I confused myself somewhere along the way. Disregard.

Comment: Right, the class is basically it's own namespace. I updated my answer to address some of your other questions. I haven't used Qt Creator for a while and don't currently have it installed, so that's about the best I can do for right now.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers were sufficient. The details relating to Qt Creator I should be able to figure out on my own.

Comment: Qt Creator uses qmake and certain settings you'd need to put in the .pro files are quite undocumented. Would you know, for example, that the library, if built as a subproject named foo, will end up in $$OUT_PWD/../foo? Unfortunately, those Qt Creator details aren't all trivial if you don't do things in the most straightforward but not necessarily initially obvious way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This applies to Qt Creator 2.4.1.

First of all, to use and debug your library, you'll want to have a hierarchical top project with two subprojects: one for the library, and one for an application that uses it. This way Creator will rebuild everything that was changed before it runs the application -- thus if you change the library source files, the library will get rebuilt automatically *as well as* the application will get relinked.

I'll show, step by step, how create the three projects needed (library, application and the top project), ending up with a buildable, debuggable, minimal application and library. You can add more sub-libraries easily by following the same steps.

### Creating the Projects

1. Create a folder for your projects.
2. Top Project

   - `File->New File or Project, Other Project, Subdirs Project, Choose`
   - Name the project `top` and put it in the folder you created in step 1.
   - Click through "Done & Add Subproject"
3. Library Project - new project window appears from click-through in previous step.

   - `Other Project, C++ Library, Choose`
   - Type: change to Statically Linked Library.
   - Name the project `library` and put it in the `top` folder that got created in previous
     step. This folder should be already selected by default for you.
   - Click through, select QtCore module to be used by the library project, leave everything else at defaults.
4. Application Project - right click on the `top` project in the Projects pane (not on top.pro)

   - `Qt Widget Project, Qt Gui Application, Choose`
   - Name the project `app` and put it in the `top` folder that got created in step 2. This folder should be already selected by default for you.
   - Click through, leave everything at default settings.

You should now have a buildable `top` project that has `app` and `library` as subprojects. Press C-B (Ctrl-B or Command-B, depending on your platform) to build it. The build should go through without errors.

### Setting the Dependencies

#### Linking with the Library

The `app` subproject doesn't use our library yet. To have the `app` link with our library:

1. Right click on `app` in the Projects pane (*not* on app.pro), choose `Add Library...`
2. Choose `Internal Library`, Continue
3. The `library` is the only choice and is already selected. Click through to the end.

The `app` project now statically links with the `library`. Change any file in the `app` project (whitespace change will do) to force a build, then press C-B for a build. The build should go through OK.

#### Adding a Top Level Dependency on the Library

The `app` subproject will be rebuilt if the library is changed, but there is nothing to guarantee that the make system will build the library subproject first, before starting to build the application. Such information belongs in the toplevel `top.pro` project file.

Open `top.pro`, and add a line `CONFIG += ordered`. The file should look like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    library \
    app

CONFIG += ordered
```

Make sure that SUBDIRS are correctly ordered: the library comes first before app. If the order is wrong, you can shuffle the entries into correct order. The backslash `\` is a line continuation character. *There must be no whitespace after `\`!*

Save the file (C-S), right click on the `top` project and select Rebuild Project "top". The build should complete without errors. Warnings are OK.

### Selecting the Build

In the bottom-left panel of Qt Creator, there is a panel with a build button (a hammer), a run button (a triangle), a debug button (a triangle with a bug), a build selector (a laptop with `top` project name above it, and elided build configuration below. Click on the build selector, and make sure that you select the Build that ends with `Debug`. This build is configured to produce debugging symbols needed to run it under the debugger. We'll need it later on.

### Implementing The Library

We will now add some code to the Library class that was created by Qt Creator for us. Open the `library.h` and `library.cpp` files. The added code is simply a static method in the Library class. This method will be used in the App to show that the two pieces in fact got linked. The contents of both files are below.

```
//library.h
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <QString>

class Library {
public:
    Library();
    static QString string();
};

#endif // LIBRARY_H
```

```
//library.cpp
#include "library.h"

Library::Library()
{}

QString Library::string()
{
    return "I come from the library";
}
```

Hit C-B, the code should rebuild without errors.

### Implementing the Application

Now let's use the library API from our `app`. Open the `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.h` files and modify as below.

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QScopedPointer<Ui::MainWindow> const ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```
//mainwindow.cpp
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "library.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QLabel * label = new QLabel(Library::string(), centralWidget());
    layout->addWidget(label);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{}
```

Hit C-B, the project should build OK.

We can then set a breakpoint in the `Library::string()` implementation to see that not only the code is called, but that the debugger works across subprojects. In `library.cpp`, click in the gray area left of the line number in the `return "I come from the library";` line. A red circle with a small hourglass will appear where you clicked: this means that a pending breakpoint has been set.

Next hit C-Y to start the project in the debugger. The only runnable subproject is the application, and it will be automatically chosen as the startup project.

Eventually the breakpoint circle will lose the hourglass as the debugger reads the symbol files and figures out location of our breakpoint. Soon thereafter, the code will stop in the Library::string() method -- it is called from the MainWindow constructor. Hit C-Y to continue execution of `app`.

The main window will now appear, with `I come from the library` text visible inside of it. This text was set on a label that was added in the constructor of MainWindow.

Answer (score 2):

There is no link between a library and classes. The concept of libraries came long before OO and there is nothing in the library format on c/c++ that has anything to do with classes or namespaces.

If you are using static libraries (not DLL) then the linker will pull out only those functions that the program needs and so the size of the library doesn't matter. With dynamic libs (dlls) you have to ship the whole dll and so there is a reason to package only similar libs into a dll - this is why Qt has for example QtOpenGl.dll separate from QtGui.dll - if you don't use opengl there is no need to include the library. The size of the header file doesn't matter to the finished program - although very large header files will lead to slower compiles (unless you have precompiled headers).

A namespace is used to show that these classes work together and to avoid clashes with other classes so I would use a single namespace for you encode/decode classes.

Comment: I was not aware that the linker only included functions that the program needs, but that makes sense.  Good information. What do you mean by no link between a library and classes? Isn't a library just a collection of classes, subroutines, etc. ?

Comment: @chris, there is nothing special about classes as far as the linker is concerned. A library just a bunch of compiled code (obj files) together with a header to lookup function names.