# Turnkey distribution of Qt Creator Projects and Libraries?

Tags: qt, boost, c++11, static-libraries, qt-creator

I am trying to set up a group of Qt Creator projects, with several custom libraries shared between them.  All of these use C++11 and Boost and are managed in Git repositories.

Currently I am using CMake and symbolic links.  So the existing directory structure looks roughly like:

```
projects/
    libraryOne/
        include/
            libraryOne/ ; Parent in -I paths, then #include "libraryOne/foo.h"
        src/
    libraryTwo/
        include/
            libraryTwo/
        src/
        libraryOne/ ; symbolic link
    libraryThree/
        include/
            libraryThree/
        src/
        libraryTwo/ ; symbolic link
    applicationOne/
        CMakeLists.txt
        libraryOne/ ; symbolic link
        libraryTwo/ ; symbolic link
        libraryThree/ ; symbolic link
        build/
    applicationTwo/
        CMakeLists.txt
        libraryOne/ ; symbolic link
        libraryTwo/ ; symbolic link
        libraryThree/ ; symbolic link
        build/
    applicationThree/
        CMakeLists.txt
        libraryOne/ ; symbolic link
        libraryTwo/ ; symbolic link
        libraryThree/ ; symbolic link
        build/
```

To build a given application, I go into the `build/` subdirectory of that app and run `cmake ..` so it will generate the makefiles from `CMakeLists.txt` (so it will put all the intermediaries and build products underneath `build/`).  Then I run `make`.

This is how this particular setup evolved, and it's rather clunky.  I want to remove the CMake dependency and make it trivial for someone who has Qt Creator to `git clone` my individual source repositories, one or more of the applications, load a .pro file, then press Build and have it work.

Other wishes:

- No need to create symbolic links
- Adding and removing files should be doable in the GUI without need to edit a makefile
- Loading an application into the editor should make the libraries available to edit as well, and the build dependencies should be taken care of automatically
- In Debug mode, you should be able to set a breakpoint in any of the libraries and the environment can stop on it
- Put the object files and executables in a directory that isn't a subdirectory of the source code

I'm wondering if there is a "clean" example of something like this...are there any good examples to follow in the Qt Creator universe?  Too ambitious to expect `.pro` files to automatically handle this kind of thing cross platform?

Answer (score 1):

The .pro files will in fact handle it for you. I have answered how to do it [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826166/1329652).

Comment: +1 for the link.  Your example is not quite what I'm looking for, because you're putting the libraries inside the application project, and I have libraries shared across several applications.  :-/  Qt Creator's defaults aren't going to work for me, especially building the libraries side-by-side in horribly named directories like `[libname]-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/`  !

Comment: You haven't tried it, did you? There are three projects in that reply: top project, library project, and application project. The latter two are separate. The top project is for convenience: building it will build the library(ies) and finally the application. It's precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: To clarify: I meant that I would have several "top" application projects using the same libraries, so I can't make the libraries subdirectories of the "top" application.  I've updated my question to be clearer about the details of the situation that I'm trying to finesse. If you think you can adapt your answer to this scenario, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Those subdirectories don't have to be physically subdirectories. They can be anywhere you want. Look in the qmake docs for info.

Comment: You'd normally put the top projects (there can be many) in the root folder of your repository. That'd be `projects/` folder in your question. They are simply convenience `.pro` files used to build the application subproject and its dependencies. They are akin to solution files in Visual Studio.